# Embedding Google maps to the site

Tags: google-maps, maps

I am trying to show a particular location by embedding a Google map to my site using [Maps Engine Lite](https://mapsengine.google.com/). However I get this **black bar** (with the text **Untitled Map** as shown below) at the top of the map which I need to get rid of. Any ideas how to proceed with this -

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are no implemented options to hide the bar, but it could be done via CSS.

example assuming a desired iframe-size of 580x160

```
<div style="height:160px;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;border:1px solid #000">
  <iframe style="position:relative;top:-27px; border:none;" 
          src="/path/to/embedmap" 
          width="580" height="187"></iframe>
</div>
```

The iframe is wrapped in a div with a height set to the desired height. The height of the iframe is set to the desired height +27px . Via `top:-27px;` the iframe will be moved 27px upwards, the bar disappears.

Comment: Sad that no direct solution exists. 
But will give a try to your solution. Seems it will work :)